# VBA - Data Counting

Tags: excel, vba

```
With ActiveSheet
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox lastrow
End With
```

This is the code I'm currently using, however, it is counting every data on column "A".

What I would like to happen is that it should only count the data starting on cell A6 downwards until data exist.

My data in A6 contains "GNW-17-001" and ends in A31 "GNW-17-026"

The code above shows a result of "31" records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

use

```
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - .Range("A6").Row + 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this satisfies you:

```
'finds first row below A6 with some data
.Range("A6").End(xlDown).Row
```